# Makefile and object file directory

Tags: c++, beginner, makefile, sdl, make

Ok this is the first makefile I've ever written. I it works and that's about it. Things that I was wondering if if I can specify where the object files go. It looks really bad with all the .o files cluttering the working folder. I was thinking a src folder and maybe a obj folder? Is there a better naming convention for Compiler_flags and c_compiler_flags? Also is there other ways of optimizing the makefile? Thanks all help is extremely appreciated.

```
OBJS = close.o init.o main.o texture.o load_media.o
CC = g++
COMPILER_FLAGS = -w
C_COMPILER_FLAGS = -c -w
LINKER_FLAGS = -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -lSDL2_mixer -lSDL2_ttf
OBJ_NAME = run

all : exe

debug : COMPILER_FLAGS += -g
debug : C_COMPILER_FLAGS += -g
debug : exe

exe : $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(OBJS) $(COMPILER_FLAGS) $(LINKER_FLAGS) -o $(OBJ_NAME)

close.o : isolation.h close.cpp
    $(CC) $(C_COMPILER_FLAGS) $(LINKER_FLAGS) close.cpp

init.o : isolation.h init.cpp
    $(CC) $(C_COMPILER_FLAGS) $(LINKER_FLAGS) init.cpp

main.o : isolation.h main.cpp
    $(CC) $(C_COMPILER_FLAGS) $(LINKER_FLAGS) main.cpp

texture.o : isolation.h texture.h texture.cpp
    $(CC) $(C_COMPILER_FLAGS) $(LINKER_FLAGS) texture.cpp

load_media.o : isolation.h load_media.cpp
    $(CC) $(C_COMPILER_FLAGS) $(LINKER_FLAGS) load_media.cpp

clean:
        \rm *.o *~ run
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- There is no need to pass linker flags to the compile stage. You only them when you link the final executable.
- Traditionally (aligned with `make` defaults) the flags variables are `CFLAGS` for C compiler, `CXXFLAGS` for C++ compiler, and `LDFAGS` for the link stage specifics. It is not recommended however to have `-c` as a part of `CFLAGS`: the `CFLAGS` can be reused for non-compile action (e.g. dependency generation as described below).
- `exe` is a phony target (and better be specified as such); a file named `exe` is never created, so it is never up to date, and the makefile forces linking even if nothing has been changed. I recommend to change the link recipe to

  ```
  $(OBJ_NAME): $(OBJS)
      ....
  ```
- **Stem rules** let you DRY:

  ```
  %.o: %.cpp
      $(CC) $(CXXFLAGS) $<
  ```
- For a separate build directory you may look at `VPATH`; I prefer to to point it explicitly in the stem rule:

  ```
  $(BUILD)/%.o: %.cpp
      $(CC) -o $@ $(CXXFLAGS) $<
  ```

  As a side note, I'd go one step further, and separate debug and release builds.
- **Dependency generation**. The stem rules above do not specify `#include` dependencies. With `gcc` it is easy to automate. `-M` family of flags:

  ```
  $(BUILD)/%.d: %.cpp
      $(CC) -o $@ -MM -MT $(CXXFLAGS) $<
  ```

  create a makefile fragment which you'd `include` in your makefile.

  Since the dep and obj file names mirror the source file names (only the extension differs) it is recommended to generate them using the `patsubst` function.
- Never use `-w`. Warnings are your friends. I highly recommend passing at least `-Wall -Wextra`.
- Putting it (almost) all together,

  ```
  SRC = close.cpp init.cpp main.cpp texture.cpp load_media.cpp
  OBJ = $(patsubst %.cpp,$(BUILD)/%.o,$(SRC))
  DEP = $(patsubst %.cpp,$(BUILD)/%.o,%(SRC))

  TARGET = run

  $(BUILD)/%.o: %.cpp
      $(CXX) -c      -o $@ $(CXXFLAGS) $<

  $(BUILD)/%.d: %.cpp
      $(CXX) -MM -MT -o $@ $(CXXFLAGS) $<

  -include $(DEP)

  $(BUILD)/$(TARGET): $(OBJ)
      $(CXX) -o $@ $(CXXFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJ)
  ```